# Powershell check email address against a list of email addresses

Tags: string, powershell

I've been stuck for too long on this task.
Im trying to check if a variable string($email) is in a list of strings($emaillist).

so if

```
$email = "you@email.com"

$t = $emaillist | Select-String $email

#If statement#$
if($t) 
{
write-host "yes" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else
{
write-host "No" -ForegroundColor red
}
```

This doesn't work because partials of the string passes. So I think I need to use some regex? '^$'
Not sure how to use regex and the variable?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$emaillist` is indeed a list of strings, why use `Select-String`??

Just do

```
if ($emaillist -contains $email) {
    write-host "yes" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else {
    write-host "No" -ForegroundColor red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($emaillist -contains $email){
write-host "yes" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

you could also use `-in`

some examples

```
$emaillist = @('abc@gmail.com','edf@gmail.com')
$email = 'abc@gmail.com'

$emaillist -contains $email ## true

$email -in $emaillist ##  returns true
```